# Не работает слайдер при загрузке страницы

Tags: функции, slider, загрузка

есть функция которая показывет или прячет блоки. Она как-бы работает но при первой загрузке страницы не срабатывает, а начинает рабтать только когда нажать кнопку. 
При первой загрузке страницы  в консоли выводиться сообщение:

```
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 69,
  "colno": 26
```

Вот сам код

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDiv(slideIndex);

function plusDiv(n, slider) {
  showDiv(slideIndex += n, slider);
}


function showDiv(n, slider) {
  var slider = document.getElementsByClassName(slider);
  if (n > slider.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slider.length
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slider[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "flex";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="plusDiv(-1,'slider_one')">prev</button>
<button onclick="plusDiv(1,'slider_one')">next</button>
<div>
  <div class="slider_one">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_one">
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_one">
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="plusDiv(-1,'slider_two')">prev</button>
<button onclick="plusDiv(1,'slider_two')">next</button>
<div>
  <div class="slider_two">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_two">
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_two">
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Cannot read property 'style' of undefined_    Переведете сами, или вам помочь ?

Comment: я понимаю что оно не может присвоить стиль undefined, я не понимаю как указать по умолчанию что б был нужный стиль